# Time to run znapzend job

Tags: cron, znapzend

I have setup znapzend and have created the following job:

```
/opt/znapzend/bin/znapzendzetup create --recursive --mbuffer=/usr/bin/mbuffer --mbuffersize=1G \
> --tsformat='znapzend-%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S' \
> SRC '7d=>24h' tanknas01/datashares/data03 \
> DST:a '7d=>24h' tanknas01/datashares/data03 \
> DST:b '1m=>1d' root@sgtestnas02:tanknas02/datashares/data03
```

Checking in the ZFS snapshot, the job are run at 0000 hrs

```
tanknas01/datashares/data03@znapzend-2016-06-15-000000                  0      -    19K  -
tanknas01/datashares/data03/CS_SG_HQIT@znapzend-2016-06-15-000000       0      -    20K  -
tanknas01/datashares/data03/CS_SG_HQIT_SOP@znapzend-2016-06-15-000000   0      -    20K  -
```

Checking in cron, there is no entry with regard to znapzend so I am wondering where do znapzend store the scheduling configuration?

How do we set it such that the job are run at a specified time?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but for future reference I'm answering anyway.

znapzend stores the schedule configuration in the filesystem metadata, not in a file in the filesystem itself.  See the top of the README here:

https://github.com/oetiker/znapzend/blob/master/README.md

znapzend is designed to run as a daemon and handles scheduling itself, so there is no entry in cron for it.  If you are running systemd on your machines I would recommend adding a service file for it that will ensure it gets restarted if the daemon crashes for some reason.

Comment: I have tested by setting up a test environment and sending some snapshot over but at the destination system, I cannot find the data so I do not know how this znapzend work. Sending email to the author and there are no reply. After a few variation of testing, I gave up and there are no good examples.